# calling an external py file while running a onefile pyinstaller program

Tags: pyinstaller

PROG.exe has been generated thanks to pyinstaller with the One file option.
at the running time, i want that the main program PROG.exe call a function in the file external.py.
the goal is to modify easily the function inside external.py without recompiling the PROG.exe

in the main PROG.py (later compile to PROG.exe) i add:

from external import *
if **name** == "**main**":
mycode(10)

in the file external.py
def mycode(a):
print ('my value is ', a)

pyinstaller imports and all modules (including external.py) and compile them in the PROG.exe file, but never call the external.py i dropped in the same directory as the PROG.exe. i do not want to use pyinstaller one folder option.

any way to make it working ? thank you